# How do I quickly transform an expression into a null check?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse. I am often using `java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(T,String)` to check for not-nullness and throw an exception with an appropriate message when given param is null.

For example, when I generate a constructor with the help of Eclipse:

```
public Person(String firstName,String lastName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

In case parameters are mandatory (not all might be) I would like to change it to something more robust

```
public Person(String firstName,String lastName){
    this.firstName = requireNonNull(firstName,"firstName is required"); //static import omitted
    this.lastName = requireNonNull(lastName,"lastName is required");
}
```

Currently I have my regex find&replace that I use manually and carefully:

```
 Search: (\w+) (assuming variables do not use underscores)
 Replace: requireNonNull\($1,"$1 is required"\)
```

Applying this manually, especially with a semicolon `;` at the end of both, helps me transform auto-generated constructors and setters.

**My question is** on moving to a superior level: do you know if it is possible to reduce key strokes or clicks by using a macro or something else (no custom plugins if possible please) so that **the editor selection** becomes transformed into a `requireNonNull` invocation?

E.g.

```
public Person(String firstName,String lastName){
    this.firstName = __firstName__; //__ means editor highlight
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

Becomes

```
import static java.util.Objects.*;

public Person(String firstName,String lastName){
    this.firstName = requireNonNull(firstName,"firstName is required"); 
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

E.g.

```
public Person(Individual other){ //Individual might carry null values out of my control
    requireNonNull(other);
    this.firstName = __other.getFirstName()__; //__ means editor highlight
    this.lastName = other.getLastName();
}
```

Becomes

```
public Person(Individual other){
    requireNonNull(other);
    this.firstName = requireNonNull(other.getFirstName(),"other.getFirstName() is required"); //I may modify the text later, but this is a good starting point
    this.lastName = other.getLastName();
}
```

The addition of the static import to the source file is not mandatory, i.e. I can use `Favorites` to let Eclipse add the import for me after literals have been replaced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Eclipses Code Templates for that. Go to *Settings > Java > Editor > Templates* and create a new template for the Java context. Uncheck "Automatically insert" and paste the following code into the Pattern field:

```
${:importStatic('java.util.Objects.requireNonNull')}requireNonNull(${word_selection}, "${word_selection} is required")${cursor}
```

Now you can access this template in your code by selecting the variable you want to replace and press ctrl+space twice.

Side Note: You should maybe take a look at [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/). Among others, it introduces a [`@NonNull`](https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull) annotation, which automatically inserts these nullchecks at compile time, so you can do stuff like this:

```
public Person(@NonNull String firstName, @NonNull String lastName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

Comment: Great. Unfortunately it does not work to me as CTRL+space on selection does nothing. Also, if I CTRL-space twice at the end of the variable name I get "No template proposals". That makes me worried about a corrupted workspace configuration. Will work on that